# Google Checkout for Android

Tags: android, google-checkout

I want to develop a shopping cart type application in android where the user 
needs to purchase the products from the list of products. Once the 
user selects the product, the payment should be made by opening Google Checkout. 
Please let me know what you people think about this. 
Hope to get the answer quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're interested in more information about in-app purchase frameworks.

For Android apps have a look at the Android Market In-app Billing:

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html

For Web apps have a look at Google In-App Payments:

http://code.google.com/apis/inapppayments/docs/index.html